# Why doesn't commons-daemon ./configure recognize $JAVA_HOME?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path, configure

I'm trying to install a tomcat 7 server. I'm following [these instructions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) from the tomcat 7 docs. I also set my `JAVA_HOME` variable in `~/bashrc` as well as `~/.bash_profile` and `/etc/profile`. I can do `$JAVA_HOME` or `sudo $JAVA_HOME` in a login shell and a user shell and I get the expected result in all cases. However, when I do on any shell:

```
user@debian:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/commons-daemon-1.0.15-native-src/unix$ sudo ./configure
```

I get:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking cached host system type... ok
*** C-Language compilation tools ***
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
*** Host support ***
checking C flags dependant on host system type... ok
*** Java compilation tools ***
checking for JDK location... configure: error: Java Home not defined. Rerun with --with-java=... parameter
```

Did I miss something? Of course, I will use `--with-java=...` but I'm very confused by the fact that it doesn't work.

I have also tried to understand what's going on in the configure script and I found the right place but I don't really understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a typo in my `~/.bashrc`. Problem solved.